# scraping data from search query with PHP

Tags: php, autocomplete, scrape

I'm using PHP, also a complete noob at it.

So I have this URL that takes queries and returns a data file with some matches.

Say www.example.com/search?q=$query
where $query is whatever the search term is.

However when you go to the URL in your browser it downloads a text file with the information in it.

I want to run through the whole alphabet and every combination of letters up to 10 letters and extract the data from all the returned files and store it in a database.

I'm not exactly sure how to go about opening each URL from the PHP script. Is there a better way to do this than downloading each file and extracting the info then deleting the file?

What I have below doesn't work at all.

```
$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for ($i=0; $i<=25; $i++){
    $query = $alphabet[$i];
    $url = "www.example.com/search?q=$query";
    $html = fopen($url);
    $stringify = (string)$html;
    echo $stringify;
}
```

Comment: is your script running on the same server as your files?

Comment: I know you're not doing anything serious with the script, but make sure you take any input data like this and scrub it.  If the data was maliciously crafted, it could easily do bad things to your database.  There are plenty of related questions and answers here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: anyways, if this script is running on the same server, the easier thing to do would be to use glob() and grab all [a-zA-Z]{1,10}.txt (or whatever file extension) files in your directory and then loop through them.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't cast a file handle resource to `string`

Comment: You do understand that every combination of letters from 1 to 10 would make ~146 trillion results, right? You may need re-think what you need to do - whatever you're doing probably isn't going to be viable.

Comment: @Phil Brown: well you *can* but you will get something like "Resource id #1" as the value :P  but he also neglected to add 2nd argument to that fopen()

Comment: @Crayon Should have clarified further... You can't cast a file handle resource to string to read the file contents.

Comment: @Phil I know I was just being cheeky hence the :P

Comment: @Christian I actually get ~3.6 quadrillion `26^11 - 26`. That's every combination of letters from one to ten characters per combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just *open a file from an URL*. You need to use an HTTP client library in order to get the files. This link may come in handy: [HTTP Client Library for PHP](http://willnorris.com/2009/03/http-client-library-for-php)

---

EDIT: based on alex's comment, you may want to check `allow_url_fopen` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: You can if `allow_url_fopen` is on in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = fopen($url);
```

This wouldn't work. fopen returns a file handle, not a file. You'd have to `fread()` on that filehandle to actually read data.

What you'd want is `file_get_contents()`, at bare mininum.